# jQuery validation has stopped working

Tags: jquery, html

Here's the form that was formerly working. I just went back to it today and for some weird reason, it stopped validating.

Would appreciate if anyone could take a look. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html>
          <head>
          <title>Simple Form Validation</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                  name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
                  email: {// compound rule
                  required: true,
                  email: true
                },
                url: {
                  url: true
                },
                comment: {
                  required: true
                }
                },
                messages: {
                  comment: "Please enter a comment.",
                  name: " * Required.",
                  email: "* Required"
                }
              });
            });
          </script>

          <style type="text/css">
            * { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; }
            .submit { margin-left: 125px; margin-top: 10px;}
            .label { display: block; float: left; width: 120px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5px; }
            .form-row { padding: 5px 0; clear: both; width: 700px; }
            label.error { width: 250px; display: block; float: left; color: red; padding-left: 10px; }
            input[type=text], textarea { width: 250px; float: left; }
            textarea { height: 50px; }
          </style>
          </head>


          <body>
            <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
              <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
              <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>

              <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL</span><input type="text" name="url" /></div>
              <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your comment *</span><textarea name="comment" ></textarea></div>
              <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it works to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/fYgXD/

Comment: I will test is again, it didn't seem to work - been trying it for 10 minutes.

Comment: I got it working now, was running the wrong copy. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you change the `jquery.validate` to the same version used in Helen's question, it **does not** work: http://jsfiddle.net/fYgXD/2/

Comment: Directly using the trunk is a bad idea. :)

Comment: @Jim - That is true, I was not dreaming, the link jquery link does not work anymore. I guess it's been blocked. I just selected bnl's answer as that's the only one available.